# VHDL parallel execution of statements using variables

Tags: vhdl

If a, b, c and d are variables, then this does not execute in parallel:

```
a := b;
c := a;
```

But what about the following:

```
a := b;
c := d;
```

Do these statements run concurrently or sequentially?

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: In the first code sample, variable c is dependent on a so it only executes after a := b. In the second code sample there are no dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no dependance between two assignments in a VHDL process, as in your second example, the synthesiser can choose how to infer the logic from the code as long as the output is equivelent and meets the supplied constraints.

In practice the two statements will be executed in parallel as the synthesiser will work out that they are not connected and create separate logic to deal with the two assignments.

The best way I find to understand how the synthesiser is inferring logic from your VHDL code is to look at the schematics representation of the tool's output after the elaboration and synthesis steps for a simple design and tweak things to see how it changes.